# how to add a serial number column in a view?

Tags: views, entities

I created a view in drupal and needs some serial numbering as the first column which is not there in the content type on which I created the view. My question is how to add that serial number field in this view like this

```
cand_name | phone_num | email id
```

is my view

I want it like this..

```
sno | cand_name | phone_num | email id
```

hope I am clear, write comments if it needs still clear explanation.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use **Global: view result counter** field defined in a view.

OR if you want a serial field for the content type you can use

the module [serial field](https://drupal.org/project/serial)

Comment: Ah!!! You are little bit fast rather than me.

Comment: I am unable to add a serial field directly to a view when its part of field collection, though?

Comment: you can use views relationship to get the fields inside the field collection

Answer (score 5):

Yon can follow below step to add serial number column.

- Administration -> Structure -> Views
- Edit your view.
- Add new fields in your view.
- Add "Global: View result counter" field from global section to your view.

> "Global: View result counter" field display the count number of rows
>   in your view result.